# Keep vertical scrollbar in view when scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm creating a table with static headers and min-width columns. This requires 2 scroll bars: vertical and horizontal.

Now, the vertical scroll bar should only scroll through the table rows, since the headers are static.

When scrolling horizontally, however, both the rows and the headers should scroll. I've accomplished this by having a container that holds both the headers and the body with an overflow-x: auto. The body div has overflow-y: auto.

The problem with this is that, since the body is a child of the horizontal scroll div, the vertical scroll bar is out of view unless you scroll all the way to the right.

I'd like to have both scroll bars always visible, but still only scroll their intended content.

I created a codepen to demonstrate this isue:

https://codepen.io/ntroncoso/pen/rmbrYQ

The important parts are the tableContainer and body:

```
#tableContainer
{
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#body
{
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

These both produce the needed scroll bars, but the vertical hides when the body content is too wide. If there's an viable solution in Javascript, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually change the "min-width" to a max width and get rid of the "overflow-x:auto;"

https://codepen.io/morganfens/pen/vmMazK

```
<div id="html">
 <div id="container">
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <div id="body">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="head">Header 1</div>
        <div class="head">Header 2</div>
        <div class="head">Header 3</div>
        <div class="head">Header 4</div>
      </div>
        <table id="table">
    <tr><td>R1C1</td><td>R1C2</td><td>R1C3</td><td>R1C4</td</tr>
    <tr><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td><td>R2C3</td><td>R2C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R3C1</td><td>R3C2</td><td>R3C3</td><td>R3C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R4C1</td><td>R4C2</td><td>R4C3</td><td>R4C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R5C1</td><td>R5C2</td><td>R5C3</td><td>R5C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R6C1</td><td>R6C2</td><td>R6C3</td><td>R6C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R7C1</td><td>R7C2</td><td>R7C3</td><td>R7C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R8C1</td><td>R8C2</td><td>R8C3</td><td>R8C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R9C1</td><td>R9C2</td><td>R9C3</td><td>R9C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R10C1</td><td>R10C2</td><td>R10C3</td><td>R10C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R11C1</td><td>R11C2</td><td>R11C3</td><td>R11C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R12C1</td><td>R12C2</td><td>R12C3</td><td>R12C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R13C1</td><td>R13C2</td><td>R13C3</td><td>R13C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R14C1</td><td>R14C2</td><td>R14C3</td><td>R14C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R15C1</td><td>R15C2</td><td>R15C3</td><td>R15C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R16C1</td><td>R16C2</td><td>R16C3</td><td>R16C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R17C1</td><td>R17C2</td><td>R17C3</td><td>R17C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R18C1</td><td>R18C2</td><td>R18C3</td><td>R18C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R19C1</td><td>R19C2</td><td>R19C3</td><td>R19C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R20C1</td><td>R20C2</td><td>R20C3</td><td>R20C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R21C1</td><td>R21C2</td><td>R21C3</td><td>R21C4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R22C1</td><td>R22C2</td><td>R22C3</td><td>R22C4</td></tr>  
    </table>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      The footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tableContainer
{
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#body
{
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#header{
  display: flex;
  flex: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, in your example, the headers don't scroll at all, so the headers and column data become misaligned.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I updated it again, should work now, just needed to add the header div into the main body div and add a little margin to the bottom

Comment: Sorry, this still does not accomplish what I'm trying to do. The headers are scrolling out of view. If you look at my original example, it functions exactly as I intend. I simply want the vertical scroll bar to always be visible. Currently it scrolls out of view when using the horizontal scroll bar.